# How to get the callback event outside the scope of object?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I'm using `Chart.js` with a [plugin](https://github.com/chrispahm/chartjs-plugin-dragdata) to drag data points. The chart needs a `options` object to be passed to customize it and triggers a callback passed along with options when there is a `dragEnd` event. I want to modify the `options` object's dataset when there is a event triggered. How do I get the event outside its scope so that I can do manupulations.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-line-chart',
  templateUrl: './line-chart.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./line-chart.component.css']
})
export class LineChartComponent implements OnInit {

  @ViewChild('myChart') myChart: BaseChartDirective;

  public chartInstance: Chart;
  public context: CanvasRenderingContext2D;

  public options: any = {
    type: 'line',
    data: {
      labels: [2010, 2011, 2012, 2013, 2014],
      datasets: [
        {
          label: 'Marks',
          data: [120, 90, 30, 50, 20, 30],
          borderWidth: 3,
          borderColor: "#00a2e8",
          fill: false
        }
      ]
    },
    options: {
      dragDataRound: 0,
      dragData: true,
      scales: {
        yAxes: [{
          ticks: {
            reverse: false
          }
        }]      
      },
      onDragEnd: function (e, datasetIndex, index, value) {
          console.log('Event Triggered'); // This works fine.
          //Here I want to trigger a function outside its scope.      
          this.dragEndEvent(e, datasetIndex, index, value);
      }
    }
  };

  dragEndEvent(e, datasetIndex, index, value) {
    //Do some manipulations on the myChartOptions object. 
    // When this event is triggered, I cannot acccess options object. 
    // console.log(this.options); 
    //Error: Cannot read property 'options' of undefined
  }


  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    this.chartInstance = new Chart(this.myChart.ctx, this.options);
  }
}
```

Comment: The syntax of this snippet is not correct. Is this part of a `class` construct maybe?

Comment: @trincot Yes I kept only a portion of it for simplicity.

Comment: Well, it is critical to the question -- the solution depends on it. Could you please edit your question and at least add the class wrapper around it, so it becomes valid JavaScript?

Comment: Seems like a `this` type problem now that you mention `class`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to use arrow functon to refer this context

**Try this:**

```
public myChartOptions = {
  type: 'line',
  data: {...}, 
  options: {    
    dragData: true,
    dragX: false,
    dragDataRound: 0,
    dragOptions: {
      magnet: {
        to: Math.round
      }
    },    
    onDragEnd: (e, datasetIndex, index, value) => {
      console.log('Event Triggered'); // This works fine.
      //Here I want to trigger a function outside its scope.      
      this.dragEndEvent(e, datasetIndex, index, value);
    }
  }
}

dragEndEvent(e, datasetIndex, index, value) {
    //Do some manipulations on the myChartOptions object. 
    // This is not getting triggered.
}
```

Comment: This may not work as `this` will be in the scope of the callback `onDragEnd`.

Comment: @GetSet not with arrow functions

Comment: I tried it but then I cannot access options from within the triggered callback.

Comment: @Chellappanவ I have updated my question with complete code. Error says,  Cannot read property 'options' of undefined

Comment: In your question still you are using function expression

Comment: Thanks. I did not notice the arrow functions. Its working. Can you please explain how is that different from a normal named function.

Comment: Every new function created by function statement, defined its own this value based on how the function was called. Using arrow function will refer to current class object